# creating excel file via php and downloading it in android

Tags: php, android, android-asynctask, phpexcel

Using phpExcel, an excel file has been created in the server.

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
// Save Excel file in server
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('newrecord.xlsx');
```

Class with AsyncTask has been used as

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.1.1.5/connect/createexcelreport.php");

    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(responseString);
        int success = jsonObj.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
        if (success==1){
            //file has been created. 
            //through browser, I can access it in http://10.1.1.5/connect/newreport.xlsx
```

Can anyobdy please share how would i get it in android in this thread.
I tried

```
if(success==1){
InputStream data = response.getEntity().getContent();
        try {
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("newrecord.xlsx");
            try {
                ByteStreams.copy(data, output);
            } finally {
                Closeables.close(output, true);
            }
        } finally {
         ..............
        }
```

But it gives file not found exception. 
NewBie, please be Nice.

**I have already searched any possible solutions. So please compare the questions before tagging duplicate**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By saving to a filename like `newrecord.xlsx` you're saving the file to the webserver where you're running PHP. If you want to send it as a response directly to the calling client (your android device), then you need to save it to `php://output` (sending the appropriate headers).

```
// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```